# Things to do in Lindau, Germany

Tags: germany

My wife is a scientist and was invited to the Lindau conference for Nobel laureates. While this is a fantastic opportunity, I've been asked if I want to accompany her to Lindau for a week while she attends the conference.

I've been told I'll be unable to attend any of the events, and the days typically are booked from 8AM until 8PM. I suspect I'll have a lot of time on my hands.

Is there anything people might recommend I do while visiting Lindau? Please be aware that I will likely be travelling alone during my visit so preference to things that make sense to do alone.

Added Context: It will be mid-end June. As far as my own interests, drinking/social, technology, and any sort of unique experiences (things I won't get anywhere else such as local customs/traditions).

Comment: That's hard to answer without even knowing what kind of things you like to do. And opinion based, too.

Comment: Enjoy Lake Constance, the view of the Alps and possibly Switzerland across the lake.

Comment: there are suggestions [on Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Lindau).

Comment: Not sure if your question is on-topic here, but if it doesn't get closed, you should at least include the time of the year. Around lake constance, there are way more activities available in summer than in winter.

Answer (score 4):

You are not limited to this small beautiful picturesque town but you could literally walk all the way to Austria and Switzerland, or take a local train if you don't fancy long walks.

In about 2 hours you are able to reach Munich, Zurich or the micro state of Lichtenstein.

Answer (score 4):

The main attractions outside of the city are

- the lake: take a [boat trip](https://www.bsb.de/en) on Lake Constance to another city (e.g. Meersburg), the Mainau island, or just a round trip.
- the mountains, e.g. the cable car to the [Pfänder](https://www.pfaenderbahn.at/en).

There are other cities, mountains, gorges, castles etc. to explore, especially if you rent a car. If you are willing to drive an hour or two, you could even visit the Rheinfall, Schaffhausen, Zugspitze, Neuschwanstein, or such curiosities as the Salem Affenberg.

Most cities and larger villages in the area have their own tourist information (e.g. [Lindau](https://www.lindau.de/en)). They will be happy to answer your questions in advance. You can also just walk in when you are there. They are also the place to ask about guided tours, events, museums, city maps, etc.

---

Edit: Regarding technology, there are the Zeppelin and Dornier museums in Friedrichshafen, and an amateur radio fair, the [Ham Radio](https://www.hamradio-friedrichshafen.com).